# Printing out all titles ending in '.txt' ( Python )

Tags: python

My objective is to print out all available files that end in '.txt' inside a folder, I'm unsure how to do so. 
Thank you for reading.

Comment: You could have easily googled this one.

Comment: Hint: Use `glob` module

Comment: `print([f for f in os.listdir('/path/to/folder') if f.endswith('.txt')])`

Comment: @ksbg Lists shouldn't be used to print

Comment: `import os for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        print(file)`

Comment: Note if your running any sort of UNIX environment you could also just run `find <path> -type f -name "*.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```html
filename.endswith('.txt')
```

simply just open the folder by

```html
fileList = os.listdir("folder_path")  #open that folder 
for filename in fileList:
    if(filename.endswith('.txt')):  # check its extension
         print(filename)
```